# Impossible NPE in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Fabric told me about several NPE occurences that I cannot explain. They happen on different devices and android versions.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lelisoft.com.lelimath/lelisoft.com.lelimath.activities.CalcActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2328)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
   at lelisoft.com.lelimath.fragment.CalcFragment.setupPlay(CalcFragment.java:253)
   at lelisoft.com.lelimath.fragment.CalcFragment.onActivityCreated(CalcFragment.java:86)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2089)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1133)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1272)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2149)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:600)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
   at lelisoft.com.lelimath.activities.LeliBaseActivity.onStart(LeliBaseActivity.java:94)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1177)
   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5461)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2301)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

And now source code for the Activity which always initializes GameLogic instance and passes it to a Fragment already in onCreate():

```
public class CalcActivity .. {
 GameLogic gameLogic;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    setContentView(R.layout.act_calc);
    setGameLogic(new CalcLogicImpl());
    calcFragment = new CalcFragment();
    calcFragment.setLogic((CalcLogic) gameLogic);
    initializeCalcFragment(false);
 }

private void initializeCalcFragment(boolean replace) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if (replace) {
        transaction.replace(R.id.calc_content, calcFragment);
    } else {
        transaction.add(R.id.calc_content, calcFragment);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}

public void setGameLogic(GameLogic gameLogic) {
    this.gameLogic = gameLogic;
}
```

Then there is a CalcFragment:

```
public class CalcFragment extends LeliBaseFragment {
 CalcLogic logic;

 public void setLogic(CalcLogic logic) {
    this.logic = logic;
 }

 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state) {
    setupPlay();
 }
```

and here it fails with NPE:

```
private void setupPlay() {
    formulas = logic.generateFormulas();
}
```

The flow is clear and there is no other property assignment. The activity is created, the property is instantiated and set, the fragment is created and the property is passed. Then the fragment is initialized in `onActivityCreated` but sometimes the property is null. It works fine on all my real devices and virtual devices. I have no clue why it is empty on those reported devices.

Comment: Where are you initialising gameLogic variable?

Comment: in setter setGameLogic, see onCreate

Comment: What is `LeliBaseActivity.onStart()`? That's where your fragment is being activated.

Comment: What line causes the NPE?

Comment: NPE is formulas = logic.generateFormulas();

Comment: LeliBaseActivity onStart is just logging method:     protected void onStart() {
        log.debug("{}.onStart()", this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        super.onStart();
    }
This class is superclass of all my activities but it has no real impact on this case so I reduced it from the source code sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android framework often needs to reinstantiate fragments for example in order to handle a configuration change. Instance state such as your `CalcLogic` is lost.

Some options of fixing it:

1. Pull the value for the `logic` field from the activity in the fragment's `onCreate()` or other similar early lifecycle method.
2. Call [`setRetainInstance(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)) to make the fragment instance survive some cases where reinstantation would normally occur.

Comment: It has not occured since I rewrote this part. Thanks.